# How to hang indoor swings

Tags: porch-swing

I would like to hang two swings indoors.  I have an enclosed breezeway (sunroom) that is 13’6 wide. The swings will be hanging between two exterior walls framed with 2x6s.  The trusses that support the roof in this area are made from 2 x4s, and the trusses run perpendicular to the exterior walls.  The ceilings are 10’.  This is new construction, and we have not yet finished the ceilings.  Presently, we have added a 2x4 to the cross member of a truss (The ceiling joist?) to strengthen it and have hung two swings by swing straps that wrap around the joists.  (I may not be using the proper construction terms — I’m sorry)!  This has been fine for children to play during construction.  However, when an adult sits on a swing, we can see a little flex.  I would like a sturdy, permanent solution.  This is a farmhouse connected to a barn, so I could do some sort of beam if necessary.  Or posts and beam.  I have no idea  what size material to make the beam to span 13’6.  Can I just fasten the beam to the top plate (if that’s what it’s called)?  Should I add posts on each wall and attach the beam to the top of the posts?  The finished ceiling will be shiplap.  I could shiplap over the beam but I would rather expose it.  I suppose I will be fastening a swing hanger to the bottom of the beam instead of using the swing straps.  What would be the best materials and proper construction in order for this to safely hold up for many years? Would a 6x8 mounted to the top plate be sufficient?  Could I not it to rest on the top plate so that it drops below the finished ceiling slightly?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Meant to say *Could I NOTCH it?...

Comment: A few pictures sure would help.

Comment: An adult of 60kg or 120kg ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand what you're talking about; would you add a picture or diagram? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: How do I add a beam that will span 13’6 on which to hang the swings?   Do I just fasten it to the top plate?  Will a 6x8 be strong enough to span the space and attach the swings to?